# Can i stop the malicious reading the class files via "java.io" function,with NATIVE code(tool)?

Tags: java, methods, native, java-io, intercept

1. we'd defend against the code crackers who can operate on the whole operation system who may read the encoded class-file via "java.io" and save the copy
2. we'd protect java-based application's intellectual property
3. this requirement was raised by several customers, so it has realistic value.

Simplex Java-JDK-JVM solution like securityManager without native code/tool can NOT be accepted because it's easy to be bypassed, since cracker have the admin privilege on the OS in this scenario.

Comment: Seems like it would be "simpler" to inject a different/proxy class - see [ClassLoader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)

Comment: I agree, either wrap the input stream and write your read method or override the InputStream method. You shouldn't need native code to just validate input.

Comment: Can not work for what reason? What's the actual objective here? You've given us half the solution, not the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @EJP, thank you for the inquiry which make the question more clear;

Comment: I don't know what it is that makes you afraid of what you profess to be afraid of. Personally I would be a lot more afraid of someone divining and replacing my JNI component than of code re-engineering in Java, and I wouldn't worry excessively about either of them. This problem is already solved by the SecurityManager. You're not going to improve on that.

Comment: @EJP, i'd appologize for making you confused and edit again; Can you do me a  persistent favor?

Comment: I don't know what any of that means. I haven't expressed any confusion, and I have no idea what you mean by 'persistent favour'.

Comment: @euse: I don't think you've communicated your actual security requirements (what you're defending against, what you want to protect), nor any assessment of whether those requirements are realistic. If you do that, it will be much easier to recommend a solution.

Comment: @nneonneo, thank you, and edited according to your inquiry

Comment: This question makes very little sense.  If you want to run untrusted code in the JVM, use SecurityManager to limit it's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using a `SecurityManager` to control access to Java APIs. The SecurityManager can call into native code if it wants.

Specifically, the [`checkRead`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkRead%28java.lang.String%29) method can be used to validate if a program is permitted to read from a given path, which covers not just `FileInputStream.read()` but any other means of reading files in Java.

Comment: @euse: if there were a bug in SecurityManager that allowed it to be bypassed from Java code, this would represent a fairly serious Java security bug that would almost certainly be fixed if reported. Thus, I think you can be quite confident that SecurityManager is secure enough for you.

Comment: thx,and i learned from your answer and have a new inquiry after "securityManager" study: the securityManager can intercept the FileInputStream.read(source), but what if the  source is a CLASS file which must be loaded when application launched or when needed sometime later?

Comment: You need to read more about the security manager. It handles the class loading case with ease.

Comment: @nneonneo,can you please give an example for " The SecurityManager can call into native code", i searched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: both, in my understanding:the securitymanager would be bypass if someone can take full control on the Java Program we want to protect, right? since they can delete(override) relevant settings.

Comment: @euse: Well, quite simply, you can have your `SecurityManager` implementation call JNI code. It's like any other class in that way.

Comment: @euse: `SecurityManager` is designed to live at a higher security level than most Java code. It cannot be replaced or overridden unless someone can get code running at that higher security level (which, again, would represent a serious security bug in Java itself).

Comment: @nneonneo, excuse me, serveral points:1.whats "code running at higher security level"?  2.what

Comment: @euse: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html

Comment: @nneonneo, what if someone delete the SetSecurityManager in java code,lets say the one with OS‘s admin privilege?

Comment: If your attacker has admin privileges on your OS, you have other problems.

Comment: I am a little curious (and my SecurityManager knowledge is pretty stale):  Does SecurityManager have the ability to block the use of ClassLoader getResourceAsStream, accessing paths that are used for class loading?  The OP appears to be terrified of the possibility that someone is going to steal class files from the system.